# PHP Warning: Module 'oci8' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, oracle, rhel, oci8

My applications are running on Linux RHEL 8 and it uses oracle DB. I tested the DB connection it's working properly. But now I am facing this error

```
      PHP Warning:  Module 'oci8' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

I disabled

```
 extension=oci8.so in /etc/php.ini
 extension=oci8.so in /etc/php.d/20-oci8.ini file
```

But none of this is working for me. How to solve it? Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

1. Find out which INI files are loaded. These are not necessarily the same on the command line and through a web server.
   If this happens on the command line, use: `php --ini`, and if it is in a browser, use `phpinfo()` which will also tell you which ini file**S** are loaded.
2. Go through all of the INI files, and make sure the line `extension=oci8.so` exists only once.

Comment: did all that but still it shows same error

Comment: @ratna There might be other files outside of `/etc/php.d` Are you running PHP-FPM or is this `mod-php`?

Comment: @Derick yes I am running php-fpm. How do I find extension=oci8.so file path? Is there any command?

Comment: @Machavity yes I am running php-fpm.